# State Water heater-Hot water pressure is off

Tags: water-heater

Previously the pilot cut off since the gas line was shutoff due to a gas leak. It has now been fixed and I was able to cut the pilot on. The only issue is the hot water is not coming out at all and no pressure from any sink or bathroom when we open the hot water. I have a State waste heater cencible and I am not sure if maybe there’s a valve for hot water that might have been shutoff.

Comment: Usually one or two valves near/above the tank.  Think someone turned off the cold water(pressure)inlet.  If no water comes then none comes out.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the hot water valve after getting on a chair and spotting it on the very top of this high water heater unit. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be a valve to shut off the cold water into the tank. Check that is is open.

Comment: Thank you so much! I found the hot water valve after getting on a chair and spotting it on the very top of this high water heater unit. Thanks a lot!